# Getting Forbidden 403 error while creating OnlineMeeting using Microsoft Graph api

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create online meeting through https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/onlineMeetings .
initially i got the 403 Forbidden error. then i give the  Delegated and Application permissions(OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite,OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All) on my registered app on azure.then 403 error is gone and i got new error  400 bad request(Organizer.Identity.User.Id missing).
then i supply Online meeting post request as follows-:

```
{
  "startDateTime":"2020-04-20T14:33:30.8546353-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2020-04-20T15:03:30.8566356-07:00",
  "subject":"Application Token Meeting",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "cb6d6636-1c9e-457c-b904-5da8265a8927"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

again i got 403 Forbidden error.
i created user with the help of https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users and https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations.
user is created in my app on azure and i give the permission   (User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All,User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All)
but error(403) did not change.

My question is that how to give user authorization in microsoft graph API.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The required permission is Delegated Permission: `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite`. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions).

403 error means your access token doesn't include the required permission. You can add it like this:

[image]

Don't forget to click on "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}".

[image]

You should implement [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-beta) and [get an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-beta#3-get-a-token) to call `/communications/onlineMeetings` endpoint.

The http sample for your reference:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/onlineMeetings
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {access token}

{
  "startDateTime":"2019-09-09T14:33:30.8546353-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2019-09-09T15:03:30.8566356-07:00",
  "subject":"Application Token Meeting",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can learn more details about [Use the access token to call Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-beta#4-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph). Don't forget to put `Authorization: Bearer {access token}` in the request headers.

Comment: I have the same problem...in my apps.. I can't tested in postman this API.. error 403

Comment: I created online meeting using online meeting using user access token. How to start the meeting with user access token without asking user to enter username and password.